# modify vuejs2 method components

Tags: vuejs2, components, mixins

I have a component `compo` that execute a method `sayHello()` when clicked.

I'm looking for the proper way to execute `beforeMethod()` before `sayHello()`. 
And if the `beforeMethod()` return false, the `sayHello()` must not be executed.

Constraint: the `sayHello()` cannot be modified.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <compo before="test">test</compo>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function beforeMethod(){
        alert('this function should be called before alert(hello)');

        return false;
    }

    Vue.component('compo', {
        template: '<a @click.prevent="sayHello"><slot></slot></a>',
        methods: {
            sayHello : function(){
                alert('hello');
            }
        }
    });

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't foresee there being a way to do this. To my knowledge, the only way you could possibly do this without actually modifying the component's `sayHello` method is by attaching an event listener manually, guaranteeing that the event listener will always be attached (or reattached), and--more importantly--guaranteeing that your event listener will fire before Vue's. Additionally, I don't believe that it's possible to reliably guarantee this. Is there a reason you can't modify the child component's method? What is your use case?

Comment: The child component is a template created by someone else. I can modify it but I don't want to do it unless is not possible to do otherwise. I am looking for a way to customize the methods of some components and that in a generic way.

Should we add in each method of components a call to a "before_myMethods" function and check the result ?

Comment: @frenchman100 did you try putting sayHello() at the last line of beforeMethod() ?